# When in the writing of "The Expanse" book series did Abraham/Franck set the final outcome for Amos Burton?

Tags: the-expanse-novels

I've read through the entire *Expanse* series and now re-reading (just starting book 6).

In all the books I keep coming across people discussing Amos Burton as the guy you can always depend on to have your back, the guy who'll be "the last man standing".

Is there any input from the authors regarding when Amos' storyline was "set"?

EDIT:
My question is primarily about the last paragraphs of the final book's epilog where it turns out Amos is the ultimate survivor.

Was this always in the authors' character arc plan for Amos from the very beginning or did it form up this way as the books moved along?